# How do I disambiguate an overloaded method

Tags: c#, overloading

I am working in a framework with the following method signature

```
   public ImageLinkButton AddToolBarButton(string commandName, string text, string toolTip, string imageUrl, string confirmMessage, bool defineID = false)
```

I have found that I need to overload this with an extra bool parameter

```
   public ImageLinkButton AddToolBarButton(string commandName, string text, string toolTip, string imageUrl, string confirmMessage, bool causesValidation, bool defineID = false)
```

However, in use I can't see how to ensure which method is actually invoked, since the call

```
MyWhatsit.AddToolBarButton("cmdname", "text", "toolTip", "URL", "confirm", true);
```

could invoke either (assuming I have my head on straight).

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see what!

Thanks

Edward

Comment: I like the named-parameters idea below. You can also rename the method?

Comment: .. or specify a default value for causesValidation and remove the overload without it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest would be to swap the order of the parameters so that you don't have to give a bool as the last argument for both:

EDIT:

```
public ImageLinkButton AddToolBarButton(string commandName, 
                                        string text, 
                                        string toolTip, 
                                        string imageUrl, 
                                        string confirmMessage, 
                                        bool defineID = false)

public ImageLinkButton AddToolBarButton(string commandName, 
                                        string text, 
                                        string toolTip, 
                                        string imageUrl, 
                                        bool causesValidation,//swap this 
                                        string confirmMessage, //and this
                                        bool defineID = false)
```

Comment: Optional parameters need to be the last in the definition.

Comment: I know.I was referring the the 2nd method which has a required bool argument. If that is swapped with one of the required strings, it would create an unambiguous method.

Comment: It was confusing because you stated not having to give a bool as the last argument for both. This would be from the caller perspective. The definitions would still need the bool as the last argument because it's optional. Show some code.

Comment: Thanks Juann - that will sort it for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [named parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). So when you call a method do something like:

```
MyWhatsit.AddToolBarButton(commandName: "cmdname", text: "text", ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> If two candidates are judged to be equally good, preference goes to a candidate that does not have optional parameters for which
>   arguments were omitted in the call. This is a consequence of a general
>   preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer
>   parameters.

So if you call like `MyWhatsit.AddToolBarButton("cmdname", "text", "toolTip", "URL", "confirm", true);`

this will call the First overload method given in question

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Comment: Link added, text copied from Overload Resolution section